# Is it possible to include previous solutions from a quadprog solver into the constraints for subsequent solution values?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, quadratic, quadprog

I have a question concerning the quadprog solver.

I have set up an optimisation problem with 96 values to be optimised and 4 constraints which is working fine.

Now I would like to do a somewhat more sophisticated optimisation. The values which are to be optimised shall depend on their direct predecessor.

Question: Is there a way to refer to direct previous solutions in the constraint vector bvec (vector holding the values of b_0)? 
Moreover: Is it possible to use conditional functions as constraints in the constraint vector bvec?

I hope my questions are clear. If not, just let me know and I will try to explain more clearly.

Thanks in advance!

Tilman

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a way to refer to direct previous solutions in the constraint vector bvec (vector holding the values of b_0)?*

I believe you mean:

```
1. solve min 0.5d'Qd-d'b subject to A'b>=b0
2. form new b0 using optimal solution values d
3. solve min 0.5d'Qd-d'b subject to A'b>=b0
```

That is no problem of course.

*Is it possible to use conditional functions as constraints in the constraint vector bvec?*

Not really: the vector `bvec` (or `b0`) are constants. Also note that all constraints must be linear in quadprog, so no functions allowed at all. The constraints must have the form `A'b>=b0` (some of them can be equalities).

Comment: For the first question this is not exactly what I wanted to know.
Let me be more clear by giving you an example:
If for example I want to solve an optimization problem with 96 consecutive solutions (as I am optimizing a production volume for every quarter hour of a day). Is there a way to use the value of the fifth solution as a constraint for the sixth solution in quadprog solver?

For the second question your answer was more than helpful! 

Thanks for your support!

Comment: In many models we use constructs like `x(t) = x(t-1) + ....`.  Inventory balance equations are a good example: `inventory(t) = inventory(t-1) + production(t)-sales(t)`.

Comment: Can that be implemented as a constraint into a solver easily?

Comment: Yes. My inventory balance example is just a linear constraint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will be very helpful!